# Server-Push Technology (aka. "COMET", "http server push", "websockets")

Tags: azure, comet, server-push

What does MS/Azure offer in the way of server push technology?  My guess is that there is not, as yet, an RTM offering for this.  The Microsoft-oriented status of this technology, I believe is as follows:

- WCF: offers TCP duplexing, but requires two TCP sockets (where one is opened on the client).  Ergo this is not COMET (and won't work through firewalls)
- WebSockets: Available from Microsoft's [Html 5 Labs](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/), but still very much under development
- ASP.NET: There is a "MS code samples" offering of "[reverse ajax](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBASPNETReverseAJAX-321a68b0)".  It looks very new.  Is this the closest thing to a MS recommended approach?

I also see an Azure discussion of "[Worker Role Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_windowsazurerolecommunicationvs2010lab)", but that does not qualify since it requires ports "other than 80 and 443."

So is this still a "wait and see" topic, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync); it's not from Microsoft itself, but it's a solution for comet based on Microsoft technology.

(Disclaimer: I work @ Frozen Mountain).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft are currently working on it, you can download a prototype from here:
http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info

EDIT:
Sorry just saw you've actually seen that already. Having said that, there's no reason to not try the prototype, heck it's probably more complete than a lot of "production" ready OSS projects ;)